# Torrc does not exist

Tags: tor

I am installing tor on mac using `brew install tor`. After I install and run `tor` I get an error that `Configuration file "/opt/homebrew/etc/tor/torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.` I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling tor but nothing seems to work. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Not a Mac user here, but a default `torrc` file is probably not installed when you install Tor from brew. You have to configure it yourself, or go with the "reasonable defaults" that connect as a client.

Check for `/opt/homebrew/etc/tor/torrc.sample` and rename to `torrc` and edit for your needs.

If you can't find one, grab the sample torrc here: https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/config/torrc.sample.in  For other configuration options, check out the [Tor manual](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en).